# No route found for "GET /voir/5"

Tags: symfony

I have been trying to follow this tutorial "http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2"  . When I try to test their functions i get this error.

> No route found for "GET /voir/5"

```
# \src\MonBlog\BlogBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

monblogblog_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:index }

monblogblog_accueil:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _controller: MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:index }

monblogblog_voir:
    path:      /voir/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:voir }

monblogblog_ajouter:
    path:      /ajouter
    defaults:  { _controller: MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:ajouter }

monblogblog_modifier:
        path:      /modifier/{id}
        defaults:  { _controller: MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:modifier }

monblogblog_supprimer:
    path:      /supprimer/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:supprimer }
```

MON CONTROLEUR \SY\src\MonBlog\BlogBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace MonBlog\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('MonBlogBlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }

    public function voirAction($id)
    {
        return $this->render('MonBlogBlogBundle:Blog:voir.html.twig', array(
            'id'  => $id,
        ));

    }

    public function ajouterAction()
    {
        if($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice','Article bien enregistré');
            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('monblogblogaccueil', array('page' => 5)) );
        }

        return $this->render('MonBlogBlogBundle:Blog:ajouter.html.twig');
    }


    public function modifierAction($id)
    {
        return $this->render('MonBlogBlogBundle:Blog:modifier.html.twig');
    }

    public function suprrimerAction($id)
    {
        return $this->render('MonBlogBlogBundle:Blog:supprimer.html.twig');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Have you cleared your cache?

2) Are you sure that the bundle's routing file (\src\MonBlog\BlogBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml) is being imported in the app's main routing file (app/config/routing.yml)?

There are two helpful command line tools to help with routing:

1) php app/console router:match /voir/5

2) php app/console router:debug